# Getting no result when parsing a url with request and bs4?

Tags: python, python-requests

i try to collect some informations from a site using the attached code:

```
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

if __name__ == '__main__':
  url = "https://www.bobvila.com/articles/post-sitemap12.xml/"
  page = requests.get(url)    
  time.sleep(3) 
  soup = BeautifulSoup (page.content,"lxml")  
  worker = soup.find("table", {"id": "sitemap"})
  print(worker)
  worker = worker.find("tbody")
  findElems = worker.find_all("tr")[countElems*(-1):]
```

But i only get this error / its not finding the table?

```
$ python temp1.py
G:\DEV\.venv\xlwings\lib\site-packages\bs4\builder\__init__.py:545: XMLParsedAsHTMLWarning: It looks like you're parsing an XML document using an HTML parser. If this really is an HTML document (maybe it's XHTML?), you can ignore or filter 
this warning. If it's XML, you should know that using an XML parser will be more reliable. To parse this document as XML, make sure you have the lxml package installed, and pass the keyword argument `features="xml"` into the BeautifulSoup constructor.
  warnings.warn(
None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\DEV\Fiverr\ORDER\ivokaza\temp1.py", line 12, in <module>
    worker = worker.find("tbody")
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'
(xlwings)
```

Comment: `soup.find("table", {"id": "sitemap"})` did not find anything, probably because you're using `requests` to fetch the page content which cannot process javascript.

Comment: yes that seems to be the problem - but what i don´t understand when i do a simply 
`print(soup.prettify())`
its also complete empty - the table has probably something to do with javascript but the  simple text form this site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server responds with XML document, so to parse it you can use this example:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

if __name__ == "__main__":
    url = "https://www.bobvila.com/articles/post-sitemap12.xml/"
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "xml")

    for u in soup.select("url"):
        loc, l = u.loc.text, len(u.find_all("image:image"))
        print(f"{loc[:70]:<70} {l}")
```

Prints:

```
https://www.bobvila.com/articles/cover-crops-for-gardens/              7
https://www.bobvila.com/articles/power-out-for-12-hours-refrigerator/  4
https://www.bobvila.com/articles/best-electric-fireplace-inserts/      2
https://www.bobvila.com/articles/best-drywall-sanders/                 2
https://www.bobvila.com/articles/how-to-grow-spinach/                  4
https://www.bobvila.com/articles/fireplace-ready-for-winter/           12
https://www.bobvila.com/articles/best-rollaway-bed/                    2
https://www.bobvila.com/articles/best-evaporative-humidifier/          2
https://www.bobvila.com/articles/moody-paint-colors-and-home-sales/    11
https://www.bobvila.com/articles/fall-bugs/                            14

...
```

Answer (score 0):

you request a xml file so the result is the xml file content not a html code that is why you can't find the table I recommand to parse the xml content into a `pandas` data frame if you re familiar with `pandas` like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
url = "https://www.bobvila.com/articles/post-sitemap12.xml/"
page = requests.get(url) 
df=pd.read_xml(page.content)
```

if you re not familiar with pandas you can write the xml content on xml file and use the parser you want

Comment: Gives not the amount of images, like the sidemap page shows.